# How to send ScrapyFileLogObserver file to my email

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to send a email to myself when spider closed
I look this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260753/emailing-items-and-logs-with-scrapy) and I can get the mail. But I find that it will write `failure.getTraceback()` when spider get wrong

part of the source code:

```
def spider_error(self, failure, response, spider):
    self.files[spider.name + '.log'].write(failure.getTraceback())
    self.num_errors += 1
```

But I want to let it can send the console log to my email like this :

```
2014-08-28 00:30:33+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.2 started (bot: shopping)
2014-08-28 00:30:33+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-08-28 00:30:34+0000 [scrapy] WARNING: can't find the images！: http://www.example.com
2014-08-28 00:30:34+0000 [email] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com
```

I need this log because if I get the `WARNING: can't find the images！: http://www.example.com` ,I can run another spider to get the missed images

Now my method is use `ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=log.INFO).start()` to write in a file.After run spider,I open it to check if somtthing wrong.I wonder if I can send this file to my email or just the 'text' in the file

Can someone teach me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 settings you can use to save the file: [`LOG_FILE`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-file), `LOG_LEVEL`; these 2 also have a command line argument `--logfile=FILE`, `--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL`.

Now in order to send an email there is a helper used by `StatsMailer`, called [`MailSender`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/mail.py). In order to use this helper you have to instantiate with all the information required to create the SMTP connection, and the method `send` accept all the info required to send the email. On the method `send` you will find the argument `attachs` which is a tuple of tuples with 3 elements `((<name>, <mime_type>, <file instance>), )`.